# Implementing NSFetchedResultsController for couch base in iOS

Tags: ios, collectionview, couchbase-lite

If we are using coredata in iOS application, it provides fetch result view controller that will allow me to update the collection view and table view without sacrificing more memory by pre-fetching the data. 
Couch base framework for iOS has CBLUITableSource implementation for table view. How can I implement the same for collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question.
Open source couchbase lite has that implementation. https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/blob/master/Source/API/Extras/CBLUICollectionSource.h